# Creating cryptography box security games in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am writing up some work on signature schemes and wanted to include some security proofs in Tikz which have similar form to the image below:

[image]

I can't find anything on this forum or elsewhere which has code to show how to produce an image like this in Tikz or another package. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  You might want to check out the `cryptocode` package, which seems to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick answer:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{yfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \node[draw,inner sep=1.5cm] (a) {$A$};
        \node at (-7,0) (pk) {\textfrak{pk}};
            \draw[->] (pk) -- (a);
        \node[below=.2 of pk] (ms) {$m^*,s^*$};
            \draw[<-] (ms) --+ (5.35,0) node[midway,align=center,below,text width=4cm] {Win if \textsf{\textcolor{blue}{Verify$_{\textfrak{pk}}$}$(s^*,m^*)=\mathtt{valid}$ and $m^*\not\in\textcolor{red}{\mathcal{L}}$}};
            \node (n) at ([yshift=-.5cm,xshift=.5cm]a) {$m\in\mathbb{P}$};
            \draw[->] ($(n)+(1.15,0)$) --+ (2.8,0) node[midway,above] {$\mathcal{O}_{\textsf{Sig}_{\mathfrak{s\!k}}}$};
                \node[right] at ($(n)+(3.85,0)$) {$\textcolor{red}{\mathcal{L}}\leftarrow\textcolor{red}{\mathcal{L}}\cup\{m\}$};
            \draw[->] (4.4,-1) --+ (-2.75,0);
                \node[yshift=-.5cm,right] at ($(n)+(3.85,0)$) {$t\leftarrow\textcolor{red}{\textsf{Sig}_{\textcolor{blue}{\mathfrak{sk}}}}(m)$};
                \node[xshift=1.5cm,above=.5 of pk] {$(\textcolor{blue}{\mathfrak{pk}},\textcolor{red}{\mathfrak{sk}})\leftarrow\mathrm{KeyGen()}$};
                \node[xshift=11cm,above=.5 of pk] {$\textcolor{red}{\mathcal{L}}\leftarrow\emptyset$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just switch colors if they don't match …